# Destructuring complex function parameters in TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following models classes:

```
export class Book {
    public name: string;
    public id: string;
    ...
} 

export class Author {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    ...
}
```

The `my-component` fire following event which use object of above classes

```
this.archiveEntry.emit({ book: this.book, author: this.author });
```

The parent component in its html use `my-component` as follows

```
<my-component (archiveEntry)="archiveEntryHandler($event)" ...> ...
```

and bind following handler to this event

```
public archiveEntryHandler({book: Book, author: Author}) {
  let line = `"${book.name}",  ${author.lastName}`;
  ...
}
```

but I get following compilation errors

> error TS2552: Cannot find name 'book'. Did you mean 'Book'?
>
> error TS2552: Cannot find name 'author'. Did you mean 'Author'?

How to proper destructurize handler event parameter/s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the handler

```
archiveEntryHandler({book: Book, author: Author})
```

you specified aliases for `book` and `author` variables.

```
{ book: aliasForBook, author: aliasForAuthor }
```

If you want to specify types for your destructured variables then use the following syntax:

```
archiveEntryHandler({book, author}: {book: Book, author: Author})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer - this is what I looking for. I also discover that when I exchange `{book, author}` to `event` then It also works but access change to `event.book.name`...